# Visual Studio - Debugging dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

i get this dialog while debugging code in visual studio 2008.

(your step-into request resulted in an automatic step-over)

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/69a123b9e7.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/69a123b9e7.jpg)

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that the option 'Step over properties and operators' in Tools / Options / Debugging / General is active.

You get the dialog box when you press F11 to enter into the code of a property and  this option is active.

Answer (score 4):

The debugger is hiding (stepping over) the internal functionality of a class property (i.e. get/set).  If you would like to step through the property's accessor functionality you must unched the box next to "Step over properties and operators" found in:

Tools->Options->Debugging->General